# Deserialize custom types without concrete JavaType definition with Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I am asking myself if (and how) it would be possible to convert specific pre-defined types with Jackson.

Given an example structure like:

```json
{
  "dataValues": {"x": <anything>[, ...]}
}
```

Basically it's a map that can have *anything* as

- simple type values (like String, int...)
- another map like *anything*
- list of *anything*
- a custom type (! here comes the problem)

As you can already see, there are a few options and at runtime unknown cascades/wraps.
The only thing I know for sure is `Map<String, Object> dataValues`.

Inspired by the idea around the type info (first solution approach), my rough idea is to have the custom type defined as:

```json
{"type": "MyCustomType", "a":"Value1", "b":"Value2"}
```

I already tried to work my way into this using `@JsonTypeInfo` (and subtypes, also `activateDefaultTypeMapping...`) but it seems that they only work in combination with type definition in the object model.

Next on my way through the possible solutions, I accepted the truth and created a deserializer for `Object` because that's the only type, I am pretty sure about ;)
What I was missing then was an option to defer parsing for "not my type" back to the mapper.
Otherwise I would have to write Jackson's mapping for simple types, list, maps... again but bad.
Yes, I could create another mapper in there but it wouldn't know the configuration of the "original" mapper.

The only way, I got this working somehow was to define the target map like this:

```java
public class DataValues {
  @JsonCreator
  public DataValues(Map<String, Object> targetMap) {
    this.targetMap = targetMap.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Map.Entry::getKey,
            map -> {
                Object newValue = map.getValue();
                newValue = optionalConversion(newValue);
                return newValue;
            }));
  }
}
```

and decide on the provided map if I want to convert it or if it's a nested map with plain values (or a list, or another map).
I think we can agree that this approach is not the optimal solution, to describe it positively.

My current mood is that maybe I am just missing a bit on the `JsonTypeInfo` or there is a way to delegate the mapping in an `Object` based deserializer that I haven't found yet.
Or an (to me) unknown third option that is so simple that I never thought about it.

Answer (score 0):

My solution now is pretty straight-forward and simple as it (might) could be.

I think the missing bit for me was `jsonParser.getCodec()` to delegate the "known unknown" types.
Also a benefit of a deserializer in my case is, that I can filter Jackson-mappable types upfront and only allow the simple types I want to support.

```
private static class ParameterDeserializer extends JsonObjectDeserializer<Object> {

    @Override
    protected Object deserializeObject(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext context, ObjectCodec codec, JsonNode tree) throws IOException {


        if (tree.isValueNode()) {
            if (tree.isTextual()) {
                return tree.asText();
            }
            if (tree.isFloatingPointNumber()) {
                return tree.asDouble();
            }
            if (tree.isBoolean()) {
                return tree.asBoolean();
            }
            if (tree.isInt()) {
                return tree.asInt();
            }
            if (tree.isNumber()) {
                return tree.asLong();
            }
        }
        if (tree.isContainerNode()) {
            if (tree.getNodeType().equals(JsonNodeType.ARRAY)) {
                return jsonParser.getCodec().treeToValue(tree, List.class);
            }
            if (tree.getNodeType().equals(JsonNodeType.OBJECT)) {
                JsonNode customType = tree.get("type");
                if (customType != null) {
                    // do custom conversion
                }

                return jsonParser.getCodec().treeToValue(tree, Map.class);
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot parse %s as a valid parameter type".formatted(tree));

    }
}
```